# Excel index or vlookup?

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

I'm trying to do a report that shows the top 10 senders of emails each month.

On worksheet 1, I have in column A the date Jan-2015, Feb-2015 etc, in column B a list of email addresses, and in column C a total number sent by those users in each month. On worksheet 2, where I'd like the results to show I have a date DDL, with Jan-2015, Feb-2015 to select from and so on.

What I would like (if it's possible) is when I select the date on worksheet 2, for it to pull up the top 10 highest amount of emails sent and the corresponding user and when I change the date I'd like that information to update.

An example of the spreadsheet would look something like this. The actually one I'm working on has ALOT more information but this should give the general idea.

```
date    sender  amount sent
Jan-15  john@email.com  12
Jan-15  david@email.com 23
Jan-15  claire@email.com    45
Jan-15  paul@email.com  56
Jan-15  ross@email.com  78
Feb-15  dayna@email.com 89
Feb-15  ben@email.com   65
Feb-15  gary@email.com  32
Feb-15  jim@email.com   15
Mar-15  james@email.com 48
Mar-15  luke@email.com  78
Mar-15  rebecca@email.com   96
```

Then say on worksheet 2, A1 would be my DDL to select the date ranges.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been banging my head against the desk trying to figure this one out.

Thanks in advance
Dave

**EDIT: I've now been asked to add an additional column for time spent which currently looks like this**

http://imageshack.com/a/img537/1409/CTwrcx.png

When I use the formula

=LARGE(IF($A$5:$A$9=$H$3,$D$5:$D$9),F5)

it just puts them in size order but doesnt reflect the sender. I've had ago at index/match but couldn't get it to work.

Can you advise what im doing wrong?

Many thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

With data layout like this:

[image]

You can use following array formula (confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`) in `F3` and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$13,MATCH($F$1&LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$13=$F$1,$C$2:$C$13+ROW($C$2:$C$13)/10^7),E3),$A$2:$A$13&($C$2:$C$13+ROW($C$2:$C$13)/10^7),0)),"")
```

How does it work:

```
LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$13=$F$1,$C$2:$C$13+ROW($C$2:$C$13)/10^7),E3)
```

Locates `E3-th` largest amount of mails, and `IF` selects only rows from parameter `F1` date. `ROW($C$2:$C$13)/10^7` decimal part is used to order ties.

`INDEX/MATCH` combination performs 2-column (date&amount+row decimal part) lookup on input table.

`IFERROR` returns empty string, if there are not enough entries for parameter date.

**EDIT: (to answer question from comment):** To add amount, use the `LARGE` formula:

```
=LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$13=$F$1,$C$2:$C$13),E3)
```

Comment: that works a treat, thank you. If i wanted the amount to show as well in G column how would i go about that?

Comment: I've now been asked to add an additional column for time spent which currently looks like this

http://imageshack.com/a/img537/1409/CTwrcx.png

When I use the formula

=LARGE(IF($A$5:$A$9=$H$3,$D$5:$D$9),F5)

it just puts them in size order but doesnt reflect the sender. I've had ago at index/match but couldn't get it to work.

Can you advise what im doing wrong?

Many thanks Dave